# ParseObject on Android not recognized in "Quick Start"

Tags: android, parse-platform

I downloaded Parse Starter Project 1.10.3, unzipped it, loaded into Android Studio. It compiles and run. As soon as I add "Test the SDK" code to the app as recommended by the instructions, I get a compile error on ParseObject (Cannot resolve symbol ParseObject). It appears that I need another import statement. Or I am missing some essential step. Would appreciate any help.
The code looks as shown:

```
package com.parse.starter;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(getIntent());
ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
testObject.put("foo", "bar");
testObject.saveInBackground();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to include the following import statement:

```
import com.parse.ParseObject
```